# Unable to login to azure via docker

Tags: docker, azure

I tried `docker login azure` and it prompts for username and password. After giving correct credentials, it gives me an error :

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://azure/v2/: dial tcp: lookup azure on 127.0.0.1:53: server misbehaving
```

Does anybody know how to deal with this?

I am able to login via firefox (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

Comment: What part of Azure? Container Registry?

Comment: @SathyajithBhat yes

Answer (score 1):

Docker [login syntax is](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/)

```
docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]
```

By providing 'azure' all you're providing is an arbitrary string called azure to be used as the endpoint. If you're looking to login to Azure Container registry, the format would be

```
docker login myregistry.azurecr.io
```

replace `myregistry` with your registry. See [Azure docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli) for details.

Comment: The docker login azure line is used in a few of microsoft's own docs though. Example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose#create-azure-context